# Error creating bean with name 'dynamodbClient': Lookup method resolution failed

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0, spring-boot-3, java-20

Java: 20.0

Springboot: 3.0.1

Dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.115</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Service class

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DynamodbClient {

  private final DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient;
  
  @Value("${amazon.aws.dynamodb.endpoint}")
  private String endpoint;

  @Value("${amazon.aws.dynamodb.region}")
  private String region;

  public DynamodbClient() {
    this.dynamoDbClient =
        DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .endpointOverride(URI.create(endpoint))
            .region(Region.of(region))
            .build();
  }
}
```

Note: Auth credential is not required. dynamodb is accessible through cli.

Context: Main database is Cassandra for this application and actual requirement should be implemented through an API call, but for some reason, we are not doing it, instead updating a record in dynamodb directly and it is once a while operation.

Comment: It is working with this setup there was a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of doing it is

```
@Configuration
public class DynamodbClient {
  
  @Value("${amazon.aws.dynamodb.endpoint}")
  private String endpoint;

  @Value("${amazon.aws.dynamodb.region}")
  private String region;

  @Bean
  public DynamodbClient dynamodbClient {
    return 
        DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .endpointOverride(URI.create(endpoint))
            .region(Region.of(region))
            .build();
  }
}
```

Now we can use it like

```
@Autowired private DynamodbClient dynamodbClient;
```

in service classes.

Answer (score 1):

The class `DynamodbClient` should have a `@Configuration` annotation instead of `@Service`. In order to configure your bean definition correctly, you will have to use this annotation.
Also, instance variable `DynamoDbClient` is not required.

The final code will be:

```
@Configuration
public class DynamodbClient {
  
  @Value("${amazon.aws.dynamodb.endpoint}")
  private String endpoint;

  @Value("${amazon.aws.dynamodb.region}")
  private String region;

  public DynamodbClient() {
    this.dynamoDbClient =
        DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .endpointOverride(URI.create(endpoint))
            .region(Region.of(region))
            .build();
  }
}
```

> `@Configuration` is a class-level annotation indicating that an object
> is a source of bean definitions.

Please see this Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/configuration-annotation.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, I will try this and update you tonight.

Comment: I did not try you changes as my code started working and I wanted to use this as an api client, so that it will be replaced with a proper api in future. it was a permission issue for me. It was working earlier, some permission changes impacted it and now after reverting that, it started working.